# xcode googleplaygames.h not found

Tags: xcode, google-play-games

I try remove/add from Linked Framworks and BuildPhase>Link Binary.
my screenshot https://yadi.sk/i/8lWcFivpbdvwx
I've no idea why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the required `.framework`  and `.bundle` files in your project for Google Play Games and the Google APIs.  The [Google Play Games iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart) is the best place to learn how to do this.  If you use CocoaPods, all you need to do is add the following to your `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'GooglePlayGames'
// Other pods might go here
```

And then run `pod install` from the command line.  Then just open the `.xcworkspace` file and you are all set.  If you want to install it all manually, see the link above for detailed instructions on all of the dependencies you will need to set up.